# Fill not filling all sinks using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst and ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, fill, sink

I am trying to make a model where I get a shapefile of conical hills in ArcMap 10.5.1. First I invert the DEM to get depressions. Then I used the fill tool and I set z-limits for each meter from 10 to 150. The problem is that the depressions on the higher altitude of my research area aren't recognised til z-limit = 150, not each depression seperatly but all of them together in one big depression with multiple sinks.

Is there a better way of detecting conical hills or is there a possible solution for my problem?

[image]

Here is a picture of my inverted DEM with some polygons. As you can see many are missing. I did not include the polygon produced at z-limit 150 so that the problem is visible.

[image]

And a picture of my model.

Comment: You methodology seems good. Have you tried using the Tools in the ArcHydro Toolbox? There are a few more "Sink" identification tools in the "DEM Manipulation" Toolbar. Playing around with the settings in these tools may generate the preferred result.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259084/extracting-peaks-from-dem-and-creating-5-m-elevation-buffer-around-each-peak-in/259197#259197 look similar

Comment: Keagan the problem is that i don't have ArcHydro, only ArcMap, ArcCatalog, ArcScene and ArcGlobe.

Comment: FelixIP - thanks I'll try it but I have never worked with scripts before because I only have one year of experience in ArcGis and this is my first big project for my diploma degree. It seems complex and I don't understand a few steps but I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: If you read post to the end, you'll see that solution is sequence of tools, nothing else.

Comment: I did it with your methodology and the results were similiar to mine. Half of the depressions still weren't filled.

Comment: Have you tried using feature classes stored in a local file geodatabase?