# Identifying (spotting) holes (pits, depressions) on surface using DTM and highlight them

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, dem, holes

Is there any way to identify all the ”holes” on a surface (DEM, DTM) - (pits, depressions) and highlight them using ArcGIS Pro?

I need for example to highlight all the ”holes” that are more deep than large.

Comment: Since there are no answers you might start with the Defense Toolbox's find peaks or valleys tools.  You may need Spatial or 3D Analyst.  I recall a supplemental toolbox which had a peak tool which would be a start for finding holes by using on a "reversed DEM by multiplying values by -1) although the sink tool might be used too.  The "more deep than large" would require more work and is beyond my initial thoughts.  Perhaps some sort of buffering would be involved. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259084/extracting-peaks-from-dem-and-creating-5-m-elevation-buffer-around-each-peak-in

Comment: If you have the Spatial Analyst license you start with the Sink tool:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/sink.htm .  Afterwards you could use other tools to measure the width and depth.  Eg, depth would be by comparing difference in elevations between the maximum and minimum elevations in the DEM over the sink area of the sink output raster.